# Exibir algo ao tentar fechar meu site

Tags: javascript

É possível exibir alguma coisa (um *alert*, ou um *popup*, um capturador de optin(*newsletter*)) quando a pessoa tentar fechar meu *site*?

Eu já vi algo parecido, que ele exibe um `alert()` para confirmar se a pessoa queria sair ou ficar no *site*. Mas só funcionou no Chrome!

Comment: Por favor, pense bem antes de fazer isso num site: o uso desnecessário machuca a usabilidade! Os usuários agradecem. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode usar o [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload).

Assim quando fechar a janela recebe uma pergunta com o texto que escolher, por exemplo 'Tem a certeza que quer fechar a janela?'.
Pode ver o mesmo em funcionamento aqui no SO quando fecha uma página com uma pergunta ou resposta que está no meio da edição e não foi guardada/salva.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   return 'Tem a certeza que quer fechar a janela?';
};
```

Comment: Perfeito, vi que no Firefox a mensagem não é exibida, apenas a confirmação padrão que o navegador faz ao usuário..
Agora, para fins de estudo, como eu posso pegar que a pessoa clicou em continuar no site, e exibir algo na tela para ela?

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus a unica coisa que me ocorre é usar um timeout para mostrar/correr código a quem decidir ficar. Algo como isto: http://jsfiddle.net/nb2mqce0/

Comment: Interessante, agora vai um questionamento:
`window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('obrigado').style.display = 'block';
    }, 1000);
    return 'Tem a certeza que quer fechar a janela?';
};`

Ao usar este código, funciona perfeitamente, mas.. porquê não funciona simplesmente assim:

`window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
document.getElementById('obrigado').style.display = 'block';
return 'Tem a certeza que quer fechar a janela?'; };`
Ou seja, sem esta de `setTimeOut();`..

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus dessa maneira funciona mas mostra ao mesmo tempo que a caixa com a pergunta aparece e não é tão elegante. http://jsfiddle.net/vfdpntuo/

Comment: Verdade, legal este site jsfiddle..
Eu testei no meu navegador, e não pegou..
Deve ser algo, agradeço então sua ajuda.