# Como impedir o carregamento de página

Tags: jquery

Existe um sistema ERP na empresa em que faço manutenção, e constantemente acabo dando suporte à erros de usuários.

Acontece que meu maior problema que tenho, é quando o usuário não completa a ação inteira que ele parou e troca de página, causando *timeout* na página anterior e consequentemente me dando mais trabalho.

A minha dúvida é simples (acredito), preciso criar um tipo de `alert` ou `confirm`, que no caso do usuário solicitar o carregamento de uma outra página (através do menu) ou fechar a aba/navegador, na condição de NÃO ter apertado o botão "X" ele receba esse aviso, para que obrigue-o a apertar o botão "X" e somente depois poder sair normalmente da página em que ele se encontra.

Comment: Vê se responde a tua questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40982/exibir-algo-ao-tentar-fechar-meu-site

Comment: André, deixei uma resposta com exemplos meus. O melhor seria colocares o teu HTML na pergunta para a(s) resposta(s) serem mais próximas do teu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso vais precisar de uma `flag`, algo que guarde o estado "clicado"/"ainda não clicado". Podes fazer isso com uma variável ou talvez melhor ainda no proprio elemento que deve ser clicado.

Por exemplo, esse elemento/botão que tem o "X":

```
<button id="verificador" data-x="false" type="button">X</buton>
```

E aí no código que permite mudança de página tens de ir verificar o estado desse data-field. Por exemplo:

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function(){
   var estado = $('#verificador').data('x'); 
    if (!estado){
       alert('Por favor carregue no botão!');
       return false;
    }

    // continuar caso o estado seja true
});
```

No próprio botão, para mudar o estado quando fôr clicado tens também de ter:

```
$('#verificador').on('click', function(){
   $(this).data('x', true); 
});
```

ou somente `$(this).data('x', true);` se já houver um oscultador de eventos para esse elmento algures no teu código.

Uma outra alternativa é abrir um alert a perguntar se tem certeza que quer fazer refresh à página como [descrevi nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40982/129).