# Mostrar uma div quando for fechar a aba

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, eventos, mouse

Galera, para ser bem direto, vou utilizar como exemplo este site: https://www.gospelprime.com.br/ Sempre que você move o mouse em direção ao botão de fechar a aba (ou simplesmente clicar nela - quem quiser, pode testar abrindo qualquer link do site em uma nova aba e acessá-lo pelo atalho de teclado [Alt + número da aba] e depois posicionar o cursor sobre o botão de fechar), que aparece uma div sugerindo inscrição no feedburner. Já vi isso também em outros sites, mas em minhas pesquisas não achei nada relacionado.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Existem diversos tópicos com mesmo princípio. Aqui, segue um deles: - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40982/exibir-algo-ao-tentar-fechar-meu-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o evento `onmouseleave`, que executa o código quando o mouse sai do *viewport*:

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", function(){
   // faça algo
});
```

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jbj823v/)**.

Comment: Obrigado, @dvd! É isso! =]